# BigQuery - Can only fetch 100,000 Records

Tags: ruby, google-bigquery

I have a table with around 50,000,000 records.
I would like to fetch one column of the whole table

```
SELECT id FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Running this code in the Web Console takes around 80 seconds.

However when doing this with the Ruby Gem, I'm limited to fetch only 100,000 records per query. With the `#next` method I can access the next 100,000 records.

```
require "google/cloud/bigquery"

@big_query = Google::Cloud::Bigquery.new(
  project: "project",
  keyfile: "keyfile"
)

@dataset = @big_query.dataset("dataset")
@table   = @dataset.table("table")

queue = @big_query.query("SELECT id FROM `project.dataset.table`", max: 1_000_000)
stash = queue

loop do
  queue = queue.next
  unless queue
    break
  else
    O.timed stash.size
    stash += queue
  end
end
```

The problem with this is that **each** request takes around 30 seconds. `max: 1_000_000` is of no use, I'm stuck at 100,000. This way the query takes over 4 hours, which is not acceptable.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Bring your code to the data, not your data to the code!" I'd be asking yourself a few questions here: 1) why are doing this? 2) do you really need that much raw unaggregated data? 3) can you not use SQL or UDFs to achieve the same directly in BigQuery? It has a whiff of bad practice TBH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather do an export job, this way you will have as file(s) on GCS.
Then downloading from there is easy.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

Ruby example here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-bigquery/lib/google/cloud/bigquery.rb